# "projectNotLinked" Error When Making API Calls

Tags: oauth2-playground

We recently started to receive the following error when calling Google Apis.

Sample EndpointL https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/reviews

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "androidpublisher", 
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
        "reason": "projectNotLinked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We have since linked our Google Play account to the Google Api account however the error has remained.  We have also tried updating the description of an in-app subscription as some other posts had success with that work around but it has not been successful.

Comment: Have you found the solution?